# How to set the path of file stored in resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, filepath

I have stored an audio file in the resources folder of my application but when I use the below path I get a file no found exception.

Can someone explain if this is the correct way to reference a file in resources or if I need to set the path differently?

This is the code that take the audio file as a parameter:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("Resources/Audio/punchSound.wav");
player.Load();
player.Play();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use resource string:

```
var music = Properties.Resources.punchSound;
```

And then use SoundPlayer like this:

```
var player = new SoundPlayer(new MemoryStream(music));
```

Comment: I tried this but I get this error:  `Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' to 'byte[]
`

Comment: It works if you take out `new MemoryStream` and just pass the path variable.

Comment: Yes, I think that your file have `FileType=binary`.